# What is redundant versus non-redundant number format?

Tags: algorithm, fpga, cpu-architecture

I'm having trouble understanding the algorithm being used in this FPGA circuit.  It deals with redundant versus non-redundant number format.  I have seen some mathematical (formal) definitions of non-redundant format but I just can't really grasp it.

Excerpt from this paper describing the algorithm:

> Figure 3 shows a block diagram of the scalable Montgomery multiplier. The kernel contains *p* w-bit PEs for a total of *wp* bit cells. *Z* is stored in carry-save redundant form. If PE *p* completes *Z*^0 before PE1 has finished *Z*^(e-1), the result must be queued until PE1 becomes available again. The design in [5] queues the results in redundant form, requiring *2w* bits per entry. For large *n* the queue consumes significant area, so we propose converting *Z* to nonredundant form to save half the queue space, as shown in Figure 4. On the first cycle, *Z* is initialized to 0. When no queuing is needed, the carry-save redundant *Z'* is bypassed directly to avoid the latency of the carry-propagate adder. The nonredundant *Z* result is also an output of the system.

And the diagrams:
[image: Figure 3 is high level, Figure 4 is the FIFO and is 'improved' by making it use non-redundant format.]

And here is the "improved" PE block diagram.  This shows the 'improved' PE block diagram - 'improved' has to do with some unrelated aspects.
[image: 'Improved' PE Block Diagram]

I don't have a picture of the 'not improved' FIFO but I think it is just a straight normal FIFO.  What I don't understand is, does the FIFO's CPA and 3 input MUX somehow convert between formats?

Understanding redundant versus non-redundant formats (in concrete examples) is the first step, understanding how this circuit achieves it would be step 2..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of background and a look at users.ece.utexas.edu/~adnan/vlsi-05-backup/lec12Datapath.ppt suggests the following:

Doing a proper binary add is relatively slow and/or area-consuming, because of the time that it takes to propagate the carries properly.

If you work bit-wise in parallel you can take three binary numbers, sum the bits at the same location in each number, and produce two binary numbers.

Slide 27 points out that 0001 + 0111 + 1101 = 1011 + 0101(0).

Since a multiplier needs to do a LOT of additions, you build the adder tree as a collection of reductions of 3 numbers to 2 numbers, eventually ending up with two numbers as output, abcde....z
and ABCDE...Z0. This is your output in redundant form, and the true answer is in fact abcde...z + ABCDE...Z0

Comment: Ok so any time you're using CSA's (3:2 architecture) you add the 3 numbers in to Sum + Carry and this is called "carry redundant" form.  I didn't realize there was a special name for that. (I am familiar w/CSA though).  So then the CPA is indeed the key, taking the 2w redundant format and collapsing it to a 1w sum for storage.  Good answer thanks